# Testing setting she session used in the intended()-method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel has a `intended()`-method used for redirecting users after a login. It uses the session key `url.intended`, [as seen here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L107). However, when testing it, doesn't seem to work. I set the session like this: `session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);`

Then this is how I test the session:

```
$this->app['session']->setPreviousUrl('some-url');

$response = $this->get(route('login'));
$response->assertSuccessful();
$response->assertSessionHas('url', 'some-url'); //fails
$response->assertSessionHas(['url' => ['intended' => 'some-url']]);  //fails
```

When not using dot-notation as key, it works. Meaning, I can assert a session with key `urlIntended` exists.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that using the `intended()`-method actually returns AND removes the session since it is using *pull()*.

Here is how it is used more specifically: `$path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);`